# append section when link is clicked - fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I have a bunch of sections in my fullpage js continuous scroll. By default, I only want the user to scroll through a select few.

However, upon clicking a link, I want an additional section to be appended and navigated to.

I tried using jquery append; however, it doesn't seem possible afterLoad.

Comment: You would need to destroy and initialize the plugin every time you append new sections. which of course, is far from ideal.

Comment: Is there a way to load all of the sections but prevent some from showing in the main scroll or is that not possible? Thanks!